# How to do grid of div elements?

Tags: html, css

Quick question, I need help and have no idea what to do, because I know nothing about html/css and got this as a bonus task along with other programming things.

What I have:
[image: One under another]

What I would like to have:
[image: Grid]

Here is css code

```
.offer-small { width: 278px; height: 209px; position: relative; margin-bottom: 25px; }
.offer-small img { width: 278px; height: 209px; }
.offer-small .mask { width: 278px; height: 209px; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background: url('../images/photo-small-mask.png'); }
.offer-small .desc { display: none; font-size: 10pt; width: 258px; height: 189px; padding: 10px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background: url('../images/photo-small-black-transparent.png'); color: white; text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000}
.offer-small .desc p { font-size: 9pt; color: #f2f0e4; }
.offer-small .desc table.compare { width: 160px; height: 48px; margin: 0 auto 0 auto; background: url('../images/offer-table.png'); color: #f2f0e4; }
.offer-small .desc table td { text-align: center; padding-bottom: 10px; }
.offer-small .desc table td.small { font-size: 8pt; }
.offer-small .title { width: 258px; background: url('../images/offer-transparent.png'); padding: 2px 10px; position: absolute; top: 120px; left: 0;  }
.offer-small .title strong { font-size: 9pt; color: #ffffff; }
.offer-small .title small { font-size: 8pt; color: #f2f0e4; }
.offer-small .title small strong { font-size: 8pt; color: #f2f0e4; }
.offer-small .view-offer { position: absolute; top: 160px; left: 150px; }

.view-offer { display: block; width: 120px; height: 44px; background: url('../images/button-view-offer.png'); }
.btnSendOrder { width: 260px; height: 75px; border: 0; background: url('../images/button-send-order.png'); cursor: pointer; }
.toLeft { float: left; margin-right: 25px; }
```

Html/smarty code:

```
        {if $random}{foreach item=item from=$random}

                <div class="offer-small">
                    <img src="{$smarty.const.APP_URL}/userfiles/photos/{if $item.item_photo}s_{$item.item_photo}{else}blank_small.jpg{/if}" alt="" />
                    <div class="desc">
                        <strong>{$item.item_name|truncate:30}</strong>
                        <p>{$item.item_short_description|truncate:120}</p>
                        <p align="right"><a href="{$smarty.const.APP_URL}oferta/{$item.item_category}/{$item.item_title}" class="view-offer"></a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">
                        <strong>{$item.item_name|truncate:30}</strong><br/><small>Cena teraz: <strong>{$item.item_cost_now|money} zł</strong> zamiast <strong>{$item.item_cost_before|money} zł</strong></small><br/><br/>
                        <strong>OSZCZĘDZASZ <big>{$item.item_cost_before-$item.item_cost_now|money}</big> zł</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {/foreach}{/if}
```

Tips are welcome too.
I mean I can handle making grid if someone will show me how to break this stupid list.

Comment: I'm actually more fascinated by the fact you were given this task despite knowing nothing of HTML/CSS. I think perhaps you need to talk to your manager about appropriate training/support, maybe.

Comment: If its a list of something, you should always use `<ul>` ...

Comment: @balexandre: or an `ol`. Or a `dl`...

Comment: @DavidThomas It was freelancing job and I am making this thing for free because I thought it would be easy(and it was but I had to ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is to just float the divs of class `.offer-small` left:

```
.offer-small { 
width: 278px; 
height: 209px; 
position: relative; 
margin-bottom: 25px; 
float:left;
}
```

As long as you have them all within a container element with a fixed width, they should fit next to each other nicely, wrapping to the next line automatically.

Comment: Divs are normally block level elements and expand to take up the full width of their containing element. By floating them (in this case left), you allow the content after them (in your case more divs) to float up next to them.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation, I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.